# Using knitr to generate .md document from rmarkdown. Is there a way to get atx-style headers instead of Setext-style headers?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am using Knit in RStudio to obtain an .md document from RMarkdown.

YAML-header:

```
---
output:
  md_document
---
```

The objective is getting an .md document that can be viewed in GitHub as a web page.

The problem that I am encountering is that headers that I write in atx-style:

```
# Header example

# 1. Header example
```

Are rendered in Setext-style:

```
Header example
==============

1. Header example
=================
```

Why is that a problem? It seems that the GitHub viewer for .md documents doesn't display those Setext-style headers in the same way
when the first character is a number than when it is a letter.

When the headers are in atx-style both (numbered and non numbered) are displayed in the same format.

Is there a way to render, from rmarkdown, those headers in atx-style?

I know that I could write a script to modify the resultant .md document, but I want to know if there is an easiest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## EDIT 2021/01/03

Since `pandoc` ver. 2.11.2+, ATX-headers came to be the default. See the [manual page](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--markdown-headings) and [news](https://pandoc.org/releases.html#pandoc-2.11.2-2020-11-19) (`rmarkdown`'s issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/pull/1957) may also be helpful).
So you don't have to specify the ATX-header overtly.

You can still explicitly set the ATX-header option, then, you need to use `"--markdown-headings=atx"`, rather than the deprecated method `--atx-headers`

## Modified solution

If you want to get the md file with ATX-headers, just add `"--markdown-headings=atx"` option to `pandoc_args`.

```yaml
output:
  md_document:
    pandoc_args: [
      "--markdown-headings=atx"
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to solve it for me.

When the Github viewer finds this:

> 1. Header example
>
> =================

It doesn't display it as a header, but as this:

> 1. Header example =================

That only happens when the number is followed by a point. If we write anything else before the number:

> .1. Header example
>
> =================

Or after the number:

> 1- Header example
>
> =================

It is displayed as a header.

What I finally did in my document was to change all the headers that have a number at the beginning, by adding a hyphen just after the number like in the example above.